# Confusion about a notation of a union type in a structure

Tags: c++, winapi

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-input) msdn page shows how `INPUT` is defined.

```
typedef struct tagINPUT {
  DWORD type;
  union {
    MOUSEINPUT    mi;
    KEYBDINPUT    ki;
    HARDWAREINPUT hi;
  } DUMMYUNIONNAME;
} INPUT, *PINPUT, *LPINPUT;
```

Case 1

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
  INPUT input = { 0 };
  input.DUMMYUNIONNAME.ki.wScan = 0x12;
}
```

Case 2

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
  INPUT input = { 0 };
  input.ki.wScan = 0x12;
}
```

But case 1 isn't compiled with g++ compiler but case 2 is compiled with no diagnostic messages. When considering the definition of `INPUT`, the results seem reversed. Am I missing a point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing part of the equation.

For compilers that support anonymous unions, `DUMMYUNIONNAME` is an empty macro:

```cpp
#define DUMMYUNIONNAME

typedef struct tagINPUT {
  DWORD type;
  union {
    MOUSEINPUT    mi;
    KEYBDINPUT    ki;
    HARDWAREINPUT hi;
  } DUMMYUNIONNAME;
} INPUT, *PINPUT, *LPINPUT;
```

An anonymous union merges into its parent's scope.  That is why `input.ki.wScan = 0x12;` works.

For compilers that don't support anonymous unions, `DUMMYUNIONNAME` is defined to `u` instead:

```cpp
#define DUMMYUNIONNAME u

typedef struct tagINPUT {
  DWORD type;
  union {
    MOUSEINPUT    mi;
    KEYBDINPUT    ki;
    HARDWAREINPUT hi;
  } DUMMYUNIONNAME;
} INPUT, *PINPUT, *LPINPUT;
```

In which case, you would have to use `input.u.ki.wScan = 0x12;` instead.